# Display product availability on Prestashop 1.7.6 cart

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I use Prestashop 1.7.6
I need to display the product availability on each product detail on Cart.
What have i to add to the cart-detailed-product-line.tpl and/or other files?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}                                   
      {if isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
          <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="availability">
              {if ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                  <span class="{if $product.quantity <= 0 && !$product.allow_oosp}out-of-stock{else}available-now{/if}">
                      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />{if $product.quantity <= 0}{if $product.allow_oosp}{if isset($product.available_later) && $product.available_later}{$product.available_later}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{else}{l s='Out of stock'}{/if}{else}{if isset($product.available_now) && $product.available_now}{$product.available_now}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{/if}
                  </span>
              {elseif (isset($product.quantity_all_versions) && $product.quantity_all_versions > 0)}
                  <span class="available-dif">
                      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability" />{l s='Product available with different options'}
                  </span>
              {else}
                  <span class="out-of-stock">
                      <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock" />{l s='Out of stock'}
                  </span>
              {/if}
          </span>
      {/if}
  {/if}
```

Add it where you want to display this information.

**UPDATE*

Try with this code:

```
<div class="product-line-grid">
  <!--  product left content: image-->
  <div class="product-line-grid-left col-md-3 col-xs-3">
    <span class="product-image media-middle">
      <img src="{$product.cover.bySize.cart_default.url}" alt="{$product.name|escape:'quotes'}">
    </span>
  </div>

  <!--  product left body: description -->
  <div class="product-line-grid-body col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="product-line-info">
      <a class="label" href="{$product.url}" data-id_customization="{$product.id_customization|intval}">{$product.name}</a>
    </div>

    <div class="product-line-info product-price h5 {if $product.has_discount}has-discount{/if}">
      {if $product.has_discount}
        <div class="product-discount">
          <span class="regular-price">{$product.regular_price}</span>
          <!--{if $product.discount_type === 'percentage'}
            <span class="discount discount-percentage">
                -{$product.discount_percentage_absolute}
              </span>
          {else}
            <span class="discount discount-amount">
                -{$product.discount_to_display}
              </span>
          {/if}-->
        </div>
      {/if}
      <!--<div class="current-price">
        <span class="price">{$product.price}</span>
        {if $product.unit_price_full}
          <div class="unit-price-cart">{$product.unit_price_full}</div>
        {/if}
      </div>-->

    {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}                                   
        {if isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
            <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="availability">
                {if ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                    <span class="{if $product.quantity <= 0 && !$product.allow_oosp}out-of-stock{else}available-now{/if}">
                        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />{if $product.quantity <= 0}{if $product.allow_oosp}{if isset($product.available_later) && $product.available_later}{$product.available_later}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{else}{l s='Out of stock'}{/if}{else}{if isset($product.available_now) && $product.available_now}{$product.available_now}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{/if}
                    </span>
                {elseif (isset($product.quantity_all_versions) && $product.quantity_all_versions > 0)}
                    <span class="available-dif">
                        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/LimitedAvailability" />{l s='Product available with different options'}
                    </span>
                {else}
                    <span class="out-of-stock">
                        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock" />{l s='Out of stock'}
                    </span>
                {/if}
            </span>
          {/if}
    {/if}
    </div>

    <br/>

    {foreach from=$product.attributes key="attribute" item="value"}
      <div class="product-line-info">
        <span class="label">{$attribute}:</span>
        <span class="value">{$value}</span>
      </div>
    {/foreach}

    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6 text-xs-right delete">
      <div class="cart-line-product-actions">
        <a
            class                       = "remove-from-cart"
            rel                         = "nofollow"
            href                        = "{$product.remove_from_cart_url}"
            data-link-action            = "delete-from-cart"
            data-id-product             = "{$product.id_product|escape:'javascript'}"
            data-id-product-attribute   = "{$product.id_product_attribute|escape:'javascript'}"
            data-id-customization         = "{$product.id_customization|escape:'javascript'}"
        >
          {if !isset($product.is_gift) || !$product.is_gift}
          <span class="float-xs-left"><!--<i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>-->Rimuovi</span>
          {/if}
        </a>

        {block name='hook_cart_extra_product_actions'}
          {hook h='displayCartExtraProductActions' product=$product}
        {/block}

      </div>
    </div>

    {if is_array($product.customizations) && $product.customizations|count}
      <br>
      {block name='cart_detailed_product_line_customization'}
        {foreach from=$product.customizations item="customization"}
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-customizations-modal-{$customization.id_customization}">{l s='Product customization' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</a>
          <div class="modal fade customization-modal" id="product-customizations-modal-{$customization.id_customization}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">{l s='Product customization' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  {foreach from=$customization.fields item="field"}
                    <div class="product-customization-line row">
                      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4 label">
                        {$field.label}
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-8 value">
                        {if $field.type == 'text'}
                          {if (int)$field.id_module}
                            {$field.text nofilter}
                          {else}
                            {$field.text}
                          {/if}
                        {elseif $field.type == 'image'}
                          <img src="{$field.image.small.url}">
                        {/if}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  {/foreach}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {/foreach}
      {/block}
    {/if}
  </div>

  <!--  product left body: description -->
  <div class="product-line-grid-right product-line-actions col-md-5 col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <!--<div class="col-xs-4 hidden-md-up"></div>-->
      <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 price">
            <span class="product-price">
              <strong>
                {if isset($product.is_gift) && $product.is_gift}
                  <span class="gift">{l s='Gift' d='Shop.Theme.Checkout'}</span>
                {else}
                  {$product.total}
                {/if}
              </strong>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 qty">
            {if isset($product.is_gift) && $product.is_gift}
              <span class="gift-quantity">{$product.quantity}</span>
            {else}
              <input
                class="js-cart-line-product-quantity"
                data-down-url="{$product.down_quantity_url}"
                data-up-url="{$product.up_quantity_url}"
                data-update-url="{$product.update_quantity_url}"
                data-product-id="{$product.id_product}"
                type="number"
                value="{$product.quantity}"
                name="product-quantity-spin"
                min="{$product.minimal_quantity}"
              />
            {/if}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, have you cleared cache? If so, you should check if it's accesing the `if`  conditions. Add a string after each line to check if `if` conditions are met. You could also try to coment first and second `if` conditions.

Comment: I tried on every way. I cleared cache first of all then:
i added to each if line a check line but it didn't work so i commented the first 2 if lines but they don't work in both way.

Comment: Please be more concise. Dump `$product` object to see which data do you have.

Comment: I did it. I have no data with `{$product}`

Comment: @Enrico Where have you added this code? Could you paste your entire `cart-detailed-product-line.tpl`file? Thanks.

Comment: I paste it below